# How OuterRef works in django?

Tags: django, django-orm

Im not able to understand how really OuterRef in django ORM works. For example:

```
    Table.objects.filter(field=OuterRef("pk"))
```

What does this mean? What role does `field` and `pk` play here and how it affects the final queryset?
Someone please elaborate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is used in *subquery* expressions: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions

Answer (score 4):

The thing to understand is that the behavior of OuterRef depends of the *context* where the query is used.

Taking the example you have:

```
Table.objects.filter(field=OuterRef("pk"))
```

You can read this as "filter the rows of table `Table` where `Table.field` is equal to the primary key of the outer query context".

Alone it doesn't translate to a complete SQL query, but here is what it means in a SQL query context:

```
SELECT pk, ... FROM ... WHERE ...(SELECT * FROM Table WHERE field = pk)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
outer query                       this is the part that corresponds to
                                  Table.objects.filter(field=OuterRef("pk"))
```

Usually you will either use it in a context that works on a subset of rows (with an operator like `Exists`, for example) or you will add a `limit 1` in order to have a single-result to use in a comparison to some field.

In Django ORM, you would do `Table.objects.filter(field=OuterRef("pk"))[:1]` to get a single result for the subquery.

Comment: Why is it common to use an `Exists` or a `limit 1` in the inner subquery? Wouldn't it be useful often to have the subquery be a subset of rows that match some criteria that's a function of the outer query?

Comment: Yes, what I meant to say is, either you will use in a context which takes a subset of rows (with an operator like `Exists`) or you will use it in a context of comparing with one single-result (with an operator like `=`)  in which case you gotta use `limit 1`.